# extend a module with submodule methods and constants

Tags: ruby, module

I want to be able to extend a module with the methods and constants of a submodule.

If I use `extend` I receive undefined constant.

The only way I made it work is using both `extend` and `include`. I tried also using self.method on submodule.

```
module Car
  module Container
    HOLA = 'Helloo!'
    def testing
      HOLA
    end
  end
  include Container
  extend Container
end
```

So this both should work:

```
Car.testing # Hello!
Car::HOLA   # Hello!
```

I guess this is a code smell..., but what other ways to make it work you know?

Comment: I pasted your exact code, without the `include` line, then ran `Car.testing` and it returned `'Helloo!'` as expected. Can you show your failing attempt?

Comment: Yes, `Car.testing` works but `Car::HOLA` does not.

Answer (score 0):

As per the description shared, it seems like you want to access the nested module constants and methods in some_other_class.

This is the module definition as mentioned in the post.

```
module Car
 module Container
  HOLA = 'Helloo!'
  def testing
   HOLA
  end
 end
end
```

Now Suppose , that you want to use this method in some class say Vehicle

```
require 'car' #this is the module file since it is residing in some other file

class Vehicle
  extend Car

  def test
    Car.testing
  end
end
```

Now calling Vehicle.new.test will print

```
"Helloo!"
```

Hope it helps!!